# How to print from a console application in visual basic.net?

Tags: vb.net, printing, console-application

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to print text from a console application to the default printer.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Visual Basic 6 or Visual Basic.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrintDocument Class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx
Example is near bottom.
Make sure you click the VB Tab-button near the code.

Also
Printing in Visual Basic .NET
http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/printvb2005.htm